# Cygwin bash -c yields different argc depending on whether the command start with c:/ or something else

Tags: shell, escaping, cygwin, argv

I'm in a Windows prompt, i.e. cmd.exe; "camlprog" does nothing but print its arguments (i.e. argv) separated by "\n" (i.e. each one on its own line).

First case:

```
c:\> c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "c:/cygwin/home/jonathan/camlprog \"foo\" bar"
c:\cygwin\home\jonathan\camlprog.exe
foo bar
```

Second case:

```
c:\> c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c "~/camlprog \"foo\" bar"
c:\cygwin\home\jonathan\camlprog.exe
foo
bar
```

To me, the first case is definitely wrong: camlprog is being passed `foo bar` as its only argument instead of two separate `foo` and `bar` arguments. I imagined it would be equivalent to:

```
c:\> c:\cygwin\bin\bash
jonathan@host:$ c:/.../camlprog "foo" bar
```

which of course prints

```
foo
bar
```

Am I missing something? Does anyone have an idea what's going on?

Thanks,

jonathan

Comment: What if you use backslashes in the full path, or use `/home/jonathan/camlprog.exe`?  In the first case, you're using a DOS-ish path (starts with drive letter, but uses forward instead of back slashes), and in the second you're using a Unix-style.

Comment: The problem is precisely that I can only afford to work with the first flavor of paths; I wish I could unix paths, but unfortunately the current settings do not allow me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has to do with the way bash handle its parameters. Actually, we need to take a look on bash's source code to assure what's really happening, but you can be sure the reason for this strange behavior is there.

I made this conclusion based on the way Windows handles double quotes and slashes. Windows does *not* handle strings the same way Unix-like systems do. **Shortly, there is no way to escape double-quotes inside double-quoted strings**.

In order to ensure this, create a file named **test.bat** on Windows with this content:

```
@echo off
echo %1
```

And invoke it passing your parameter:

```
C:\> test.bat "c:/cygwin/home/jonathan/camlprog \"foo\" bar"
```

As result you will get:

```
"c:/cygwin/home/jonathan/camlprog \"foo\" bar"
```

Which means the slashes and all other characters are passed to script. So, in your case, they are being passed to bash, which is handling these characters for you, and it is doing this in some inconsistent way.

So, to workaround your problem, you can invoke your command this way:

```
 c:\> c:\cygwin\bin\bash -c 'c:/cygwin/home/jonathan/camlprog "foo" bar'
 foo
 bar
```

Using single quotes first and double quotes later, the script `camlprog` seems to run as expected.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that Cygwin's bash does some "sniffing" to try to figure out if it should parse the command-line Windows-style or Unix-style. The two platforms have different coding conventions. The solution was to prepend '' in front of "c:/..." to make sure it's always parsed Unix-style.